# Global Minima and Dynamic Programming

Tags: dynamic-programming

I understand that dynamic programming is a divide and conquer algorithm and use recursive to solve a problem, but I am having difficulty with dynamic programming can achieve to escape local minima?

Answer (score 0):

In dynamic programming approaches, you evaluate all possible cases just like a brute force algorithm but only reuse solutions to sub problems that have already been computed. Thats why you always achieve the global solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The way DP works is that you build a bigger optimal solution from the optimal solutions to smaller problems. You don't really *have* local minima that way, so you can't talk about escaping them. You're always at the optimal point of whatever (sub)problem you're at - any time you get a solution to some (sub)problem, it will be optimal. That's completely different from having a complete (but possibly non-optimal) solution that you're trying to successively improve until you reach optimality.